# How can a string value be transformed and cast to number using jq

Tags: json, numbers, jq, data-extraction

Just trying to figure out how can this simple JSON fragment

```
[{ "rooms": "2 Rooms" }, { "rooms": "3 Rooms" }]
```

be transformed to

```
[{ "rooms": 2 }, { "rooms": 3 }]
```

I found in the documentations the reference to functions supporting regexp, but I cannot write more than this

```
[.[] | { "rooms": .rooms } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that can easily be adapted to different requirements:

```
def extractNumber: gsub("[^0-9]";"") | tonumber;

map( map_values(extractNumber) )
```

### A generalization

```
def extractNumber:
  . as $in 
  | gsub("[^0-9]";"")
  | if length == 0 then $in else tonumber end;

walk(if type == "object" then map_values(extractNumber) else . end)
```

Comment: can you please provide a working example based on what I wrote in my post?

Comment: You could use the form: `jq -f program.jq input.json` where input.json is your input and program.jq is the program.

Comment: Just trying the online tool here https://jqplay.org/s/IgRj7S2Ktf can you please make this snippet work?